# Python Scrapy: 'twisted.internet.error.connectionlost'

Tags: python, scrapy

This is the code for my spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class BannerSpider(Spider):

    name = "Banner"
    allowed_domains = ["aus.edu"]
    start_urls = ["https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_disp_dyn_ctlg"]
    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formxpath='/html/body/div/form',
        formdata={'cat_term_in':'201610'},
        callback=self.getCoursePages
        )

    def getCoursePages(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for category in hxs.select("//select[@id='subj_id']/option//@value").extract():
            yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath='/html/body/div/form',
            formdata={'sel_subj':category, 'sel_levl':'%', 'sel_attr':'%', 'term_in':'201610'},
            callback=self.getCourses
            )

    def getCourses(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for course in hxs.select("//td[@class='nttitle']/a//@value").extract():
            print course
```

This is a small part of the output. It keeps printing the same thing over and over again.

```
2015-07-07 02:27:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-07-07 02:27:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (referer: https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_disp_cat_term_date)
2015-07-07 02:27:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-07-07 02:27:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-07-07 02:27:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (referer: https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_disp_cat_term_date)
2015-07-07 02:27:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
2015-07-07 02:27:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (referer: https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_disp_cat_term_date)
2015-07-07 02:27:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_display_courses> (referer: https://banner.aus.edu/axp3b21h/owa/bwckctlg.p_disp_cat_term_date)
```

I'm new to scrapy so I cannot understand why this is happening. I already tried using DOWNLOAD_DELAY. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` with value 1 (the default is **8**) in combination with `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`.

And it can happen that the site you are scraping does not like when the client accessing it is not a browser. To solve this you could add the following line to your `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'
```

And you can read an article about crawler-blocking: http://webscraping.com/blog/How-to-crawl-websites-without-being-blocked/